# Existence of nice exhaustion - Rudin.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

This is taken from Rudin's Complex Analysis/Real Analysis

> [image]
> [image]

Can someone tell me *why* $K_n \subset \Omega$? I agree it is compact, but why does it follow that it is a subset of $\Omega$? WLOG, I took $a = 0$ and drew some pictures. In my case, $K_n$ is a sequence of annular rings. But the theorem asserts for any open set $\Omega$, so I just had to draw a noncircular region and the theorem is wrong.

Comment: I think the union in the definition of $V_{n}$ is over all points $a \notin \Omega$.  Notice that $K_{n} \subset \Omega$ is equivalent to $V_{n} = K_{n}^c \supset \Omega^c$ and we have $\Omega^{c} \subset \cup_{a\notin \Omega} D\left(a; \frac{1}{n}\right)$ since each point is in the corresponding disc.

Comment: I see, would yo be able to explain how one "easily verifies $D(z, r) \subset K_{n + 1}$"

Comment: It might help to draw $K_n$ as the set of points of $\Omega$ within distance $n$ of the origin *and* at least $1/n$ away from the boundary of \Omega$. See if that helps your noncircular plight.

Comment: Are the points that are "at least $1/n$ away from $\partial \Omega$ inside $\Omega$? That's the picture I am getting.

Comment: Yes, they are inside $\Omega$.